# Duplicating and editing power settings using powercfg

Tags: batch-file, console, powercfg

I would like to use the powercfg tool in Windows to duplicate my current power scheme and then change the new scheme (enabling me to revert back to the old scheme if I mess something up) using a batch file.

I know that `powercfg -getactivescheme` would return the current scheme's GUID

`powercfg -setactive [GUID]` would set a GUID to the current scheme, but how would I know what GUID to use? That is, how would I know what the duplicated scheme's new GUID would be?

Answer (score 1):

Executing `powercfg -l` on my machine returns the following:

```
Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance) *
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)
```

Then when you duplicate the current active scheme with `powercfg -duplicatescheme 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c` the output is as follows:

```
Power Scheme GUID: d0b7e1f3-c9ed-49d1-93d4-6ed688244dea  (High performance)
```

Seems to me that capturing `tokens=4` from the `powercfg -duplicatescheme` command would get you your backup scheme's GUID.

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem get current scheme
for /f "tokens=4" %%I in ('powercfg -getactivescheme') do set current=%%I

rem create backup
for /f "tokens=4" %%I in ('powercfg -duplicatescheme %current%') do set backup=%%I

rem switch to backup
powercfg -setactive %backup%
echo Switched from %current% to %backup%
```